# html5 canvas how to get The canvas stack of drawing states

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

html5 canvas how to get The canvas stack of drawing states?
Each context maintains a stack of drawing states.And the drawing states consist of the current clipping region(which i need) and others.
The API only offer save() and restore() method to get current drawing states and maintain the stack.
But if I got many drawing state saving in the stack and want change one to another which is not pervious one. What can i do ? how to treat the stack as an array?

Comment: Have you considered something like [fabric.js](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/)?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is different arrays to store x and y positions when mouse is down on canvas. Then you can differentiate different drawings by recording the indexes of these arrays at the time of mousedown event. [Here is a tutorial](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/#demo-tools) for such requirement. This series of mousedown indexes can also be used to undo drawings

Comment: I read the tutorial. It's only have on main-area for user to drawing which create by clip function. If I have two main-areas for user to drawing I can which the area by save()&restore(). But If I have 10 main-areas and I want switch to the second chip in the stack, I need to use restore function 8 times and can't getback because the chip is popup from the stack. How to switch the clip to second one directly and getback to 10th ?